# How do you perform batch updates using form_tag / fields_tag in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Upon creation of a Sale, an individual SaleItem is created for every Product already in existence. SaleItem is the only model that references either Sale or Product.

I want to be able to view and make updates to the SaleItem discount_percentage(decimal) and include_in_sale(boolean) attributes directly from each Sale#show.

I figure it was better to point the form to POST to SaleItem#index rather than edit so I don't have to worry about the :id and could just redirect the page after completing all updates.

I'm taking the basic concept of my form_tag structure from [this tutorial.](https://howilearnedrails.wordpress.com/2017/01/29/rails-single-form-with-multiple-instances-of-a-model/)

Any help making this functional with a minimal number of hits to the database would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit 1:** Updated strong params to allow the Unpermitted parameters.

#### Issues

The server log is showing me that the following is causing a rollback:

<strike>Unpermitted parameters: :0, :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11, :12, :13, :14, :15, :16, :17, :18, :19, :20, :21, :22, :23, :24, :25, :26, :27, :28, :29, :30, :31</strike>

Also the parameter values are strings rather than integers. See [link.](https://i1378.photobucket.com/albums/ah115/stupidsquid/Screen%20Shot%202017-11-29%20at%205.22.08%20PM_zps68hzqyw7.png)

## Model Associations

*Sale*

```
has_many :sale_items
has_many :products, :through => :sale_items
```

*Sale Item*

```
belongs_to :sale, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :product
```

*Product*

```
has_many :sale_items
```

## Controllers

*Sales*

```
def show
 @sale_items = @sale.sale_items
end
```

*SaleItems*

```
before_action :sale_items_batch_update, only: [:index]
include BatchUpdate

def index
 # not relevant as data is viewed from sales#show
 # just wanted to show method because this is where form_tag is pointing to.
 @sale_items = SaleItem.all
end

private

def sale_item_params
  params.require(:sale_item).permit(:product_id, :sale_id, :discount_percentage, :include_in_sale).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted['sale_item'] = params[:sale_item]['sale_item']
  end
end
```

## Concerns

*batch_update.rb*

```
module BatchUpdate

 private

 def sale_items_batch_update
  unless params['sale_item'].nil?
   sale_items = params['sale_item']

   sale_items.each do |key, value|
     # not sure yet
   end
  end
    # redirect_to #original sales/show.html.erb page
 end
end
```

## View

*sales/show.html.erb*

```
<%= form_tag sale_items_path do %>

  <% @sale_items.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
    <%= fields_for 'sale_item[]', item, include_id: false do |field| %>

      <%= field.hidden_field :id, value: item.id, name: "sale_item[#{index}][id]" %>
      <%= field.hidden_field :product_id, value: item.product_id, name: "sale_item[#{index}][product_id]" %>
      <%= field.hidden_field :sale_id, value: item.sale_id, name: "sale_item[#{index}][sale_id]" %>

      <%= field.check_box :include_in_sale, value: item.include_in_sale, name: "sale_item[#{index}][include_in_sale]" %>
      <%= field.text_field :discount_percentage, value: item.discount_percentage, name: "sale_item[#{index}][discount_percentage]" %> 

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Update All' %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it functioning at least by this point. I'll be doing some major refactoring to make it more database efficient later on.

#### Code I Removed

batch_update.rb Concern & any references to it in the SaleItems Controller

### Updated Code

*views/sales/show*

```
<%= form_tag batch_update_sale_items_path, method: :put do %>

  <% @sale_items.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
    <%= fields_for 'sale_item[]', item, include_id: false do |field| %>
      <%= field.hidden_field :id, value: item.id, name: "sale_item[#{index}][id]" %>
      <%= field.check_box :include_in_sale, value: item.include_in_sale, name: "sale_item[#{index}][include_in_sale]" %>
      <%= field.text_field :discount_percentage, value: item.discount_percentage, name: "sale_item[#{index}][discount_percentage]" %> 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

<%= submit_tag 'Update All' %>
<% end %>
```

*routes.rb*

```
put 'sales/:id/batch_update_sale_items', to: 'sale_items#batch_update_sale_items', as: 'batch_update_sale_items'
```

*SaleItemsController*

```
# path from Sale#show
def batch_update_sale_items
  @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])

  unless params['sale_item'].nil?
    sale_items_to_update = make_batch_update_hash_pretty(params['sale_item'])
    update_each_sale_item(sale_items_to_update)
  end

  redirect_to sale_path(@sale)
end

private

# takes params['sale_item'] from Sale#show and converts it into a more usable array of hashes
def make_batch_update_hash_pretty( batch_update_hash )
  # convert params to hash & removes indexing keys
  old_hash_array = (batch_update_hash.to_unsafe_h).values
  # converts hash keys to_sym
  old_hash_array = old_hash_array.map(&:symbolize_keys)

  new_hash_array = []
  old_hash_array.map do |hash|
    hash[:id] = hash[:id].to_i
    hash[:include_in_sale] = hash[:include_in_sale].to_i
    hash[:discount_percentage] = hash[:discount_percentage].to_f

    # pushes updated values/types to new hash
    new_hash_array << hash
  end

  return new_hash_array
end

# this method will update a batch of sale_items if their attributes have changed
def update_each_sale_item( sale_items )

  sale_items.each do |item|

    @original_sale_item = SaleItem.find(item[:id])

    # determine if sale_item attributes have been altered
    if @original_sale_item.discount_percentage.to_f != item[:discount_percentage]
      sale_item_attributes_changed = true
    elsif @original_sale_item.include_in_sale != item[:include_in_sale]
      sale_item_attributes_changed = true
    else
      sale_item_attributes_changed = false
    end

    # if true updates attribute
    if sale_item_attributes_changed
      @original_sale_item.update(include_in_sale: item[:include_in_sale], discount_percentage: item[:discount_percentage])
    end

  end
end
```